# How to add a tag for marker in android Google Map?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, marker

How can I add a tag for each of the marker,and the tag is always along with the marker?Because there are many markers(vehicles) on the map ,adding a tag for the marker so that user don't need to click the marker and know the license number of the marker(vehicle).

[image]

Comment: try adding this license plate along with the marker.

Comment: @Vera The shape I have outlined in red is a license tag.

Comment: then add a layout, that has imagview of car as marker and licesnse tags. and use this layout as a marker. Make a custom marker

Comment: @Vera can you show me a demo

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
marker.showInfoWindow();
```

Comment: I want the tag is always visible and along with the marker, and the user don't need to click the marker.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use the Marker Class
```

and refer this link  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker

An icon placed at a particular point on the map's surface. A marker icon is drawn oriented against the device's screen rather than the map's surface; i.e., it will not necessarily change orientation due to map rotations, tilting, or zooming.

A marker has the following properties:

```
Anchor
```

The point on the image that will be placed at the LatLng position of the marker. This defaults to 50% from the left of the image and at the bottom of the image.

```
Position
```

The LatLng value for the marker's position on the map. You can change this value at any time if you want to move the marker.

Title

A text string that's displayed in an info window when the user taps the marker. You can change this value at any time.

```
Snippet
```

Additional text that's displayed below the title. You can change this value at any time.

```
Icon
```

A bitmap that's displayed for the marker. If the icon is left unset, a default icon is displayed. You can specify an alternative coloring of the default icon using defaultMarker(float). You can't change the icon once you've created the marker.

```
Drag Status
```

If you want to allow the user to drag the marker, set this property to true. You can change this value at any time. The default is true.

```
Visibility
```

By default, the marker is visible. To make the marker invisible, set this property to false. You can change this value at any time.

```
GoogleMap map = ... // get a map.
   // Add a marker at San Francisco.
   Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
       .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
       .title("San Francisco")
       .snippet("Population: 776733"));
```

Comment: I have generated markers on the map already and what I need is adding a tag along with the marker.

Comment: see this lovely tutorial   http://androidfreakers.blogspot.in/2013/08/display-custom-info-window-with.html

Comment: You have to make custom info window for that

Comment: @Prashant  I have created a custom infoWindow for marker,once I click the marker , the infoWindow will display.Apart from this ,I need a tag along with the marker and always visible even though I don't click the marker.

Comment: marker.showInfoWindow();  marker is your marker object

Comment: @Prashant The code didn't work for me.The shape I have outlined in red is a license tag(That's really what I need).Once I click the marker,the other infoWindow(not the license tag) will pop up.

Comment: You have to inflate your licenese view in the customimnfowindow

Comment: @Prashant  please kindly show me your code ,the previous code didn't work fro me.

Comment: I will let u know after 1 hr. Its my lunch time

Comment: @Prashant enjoy your lunch

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Add class in your code

```
private class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter, IServerResponse, ServerParameterList  {

    private View view;
    private String _spotId = "";
    LinearLayout _mainlayout;

    public CustomInfoWindowAdapter() {
        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_balloon_overlay,
                null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

        if (CustomMap.this._marker != null
                && CustomMap.this._marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
            CustomMap.this._marker.hideInfoWindow();
            CustomMap.this._marker.showInfoWindow();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) {
        CustomMap.this._marker = marker;

        String url = null;

        // setup our fields
        _title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.balloon_item_title);
        _snippet = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.balloon_item_snippet);
        _mainlayout=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.balloon_main_layout);


        // IMPLEMENTING BALLOON DETAILS
        ImageButton details = (ImageButton) view
                .findViewById(R.id.balloon_details);


        /*_storeIdTextView = (TextView) parent
                .findViewById(R.id.balloon_storeId_custom);
        _storeIdTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);*/

        if(marker.getTitle()!=null)
        {
            _title.setText(marker.getTitle());
        }
        /* if(marker.getSnippet()!=null)
     {
         _snippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
     }*/


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void serverResponse(String response, int processid) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Response Custom"+response);


    }


}
```

where **custom_balloon_overlay** is your layout

And on map  use it like:

```
    mapView.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter());
```